# Using deque insert() to merge two lists?

Tags: python, list, insert, deque

I am attempting to insert a list of points into a deque, but I'm having trouble keeping it a continuous list:

```
from collections import deque

pts= deque()
pts = [1, 5]
new_pts = [2, 3, 4]

pts.insert(1,new_pts)
```

Output:

```
[1,[2, 3, 4], 5]
```

Desired output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

This works:

```
[pts.insert(1,pt) for pt in reversed(new_pts)]
```

But I'm afraid I'm overcomplicating things.

Comment: That actually outputs: `[[2, 3, 4], 1, 5]`.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple slicing:

```
pts[1:1] = new_pts
```

**Code**:

```
pts = [1, 5]
new_pts = [2, 3, 4]

pts[1:1] = new_pts
print(pts)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Because its a deque not a list I get:
TypeError: can only assign an iterable

Answer (score 0):

You need to use extendleft() to add more than one value to the beginning of the queue.

```
 pts.extendleft(new_pts)
```

Comment: The zero was a typo (my bad).  Insertion at positions other than first or last in a deque is usually a sign that it is not the right data structure to use

Comment: Alain,
I was thinking that as well, unfortunately the pop and append speeds are really useful in the rest of the program. I'll keep digging, thank you :)